# Difference between WIN32 and x86 in smart card project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, smartcard

I have smart card related project.In smart card field x86 and win32 has any difference.Because I have to create 32bit application in vc++.So what solution platform,Should I choose in MS visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

x86 is for Intel/AMD specific code generation, while Win32 is a general 32bit target. My guess is that the smart card reader has an ARM chip-set, so Win32 should be right choice.