# Visual Studio 2012 Platform : Only ARM and Win32?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I try to run a .exe on a XP 32bits computer. I use Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 7 64bits.

I got a message " **.exe is not a valid win32 application.

So, it's because I have compiled the program in 64bits.

I try to change the platform target in my project properties, but I have only "Win32, ARM and x64"

Win32 = x86 ?

Why I have not x86 platform on the list ?

A screenshot :

[image]

I'm sorry for my bad english...

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : Ok, Win32 == x86, so why when I compile in Win32, I get the message "**.exe is not a valid win32 application." on a 32bits win XP ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile for Win XP with Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130713/how-to-compile-for-win-xp-with-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Win32 = x86. On your computer both x64 and Win32 should work.

Comment: Win32 == x86 ... no problem

Comment: Regarding your edit, see the proposed duplicate – VC++ 2012 does not support targeting WinXP out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86 is for Intel or AMD specific code generation, while Win32 is a generic 32-bit target.
Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32, [Difference between WIN32 and x86 in smart card project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709942/difference-between-win32-and-x86-in-smart-card-project)

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit Windows platform is called `Win32` in Visual Studio. So yes, x86 == Win32.

Comment: Ok, so why when I compile in Win32, I get the message "**.exe is not a valid win32 application." on a 32bits win XP ?